# Win 10 forfiles searchmask

Tags: batch-file

I have downloaded a series of torrent files, and want to delete some of the attached files that came within them.  I'm familiar with forfiles but don't know how to set up a searchmask from a file of unwanted extensions (i.e. *.jpg, *.txt, etc.).

So far, I have captured 17 extensions that I won't ever need, and would hate to have to loop the entire batch program for an eighteenth time if I find another.

Comment: Why do you think you need `FORFILES`? That is overkill.  The only reason you would use `FORFILES` if if you wanted to use the `/D` option. A simple delete command can delete all the unwanted files. `del *.txt *.jpg`.

Comment: Or conversely, something similar to this: `For %%A In (*.*) Do If Not "%%~xA"==".mkv" Del "%%A"`.

Comment: prepare a list first with the old `dir /b /s *.txt /s *.jpg /s *.etc` capturing the output into a text file, and then delete the files in the list with a simple `for /f ` over the contents of the captured list

Answer (score 0):

First, prepare a list of all the unwanted files with `dir /b /s`, capturing the output into a temporary text file;

```
dir /b /s *.txt /s *.jpg /s *.etc >%temp%\unwanted.lst
```

see `help dir` for an explanation on the `/b` and `/s` switches.

Then, delete the files in the list with a simple `for /f` over the contents of the captured list

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%temp%\unwanted.lst) do del %%a
```

See `help for` to understand what the `/f` does.

---

So, putting all the pieces together, your batch file would be something similar to this one:

```
@echo off
set "otf=%temp%\unwanted-%random%.lst"
dir /b /s *.jpg /s *.txt /s *.etc >%otf%
for /f %%a in (%otf%) do echo del "%%a"
echo del %otf%
```

note that it uses the `%random%` pseudovariable to minimize the risk of collisions

test in your situation and remove the `echo` commands

Comment: The `FOR` command will fail with file paths and file names that have spaces in them.

Comment: Still broke.  You need to change the `FOR` command options.  The `FOR` command by default will split up the output it is processing using default delimiters.  So you need to use the `DELIMS` option to tell the `FOR` command to no split up any of the data it is processing. `"delims="`.

Comment: Thanks, folks.  My collection of "unwanted files" is by .ext only.  No filenames needed to delete all photos, texts, etc.

I think I worked it out by using this command line:

for /f %x in (P:\Batch\FILES\cleanup_files.txt) do forfiles /s /m %x /c "cmd /c del @file"

It seems to be working okay so far.  Have to add the extra '%' to a batch file and then turn it loose on a directory.

If I have made a mistake somewhere, someone please chime in!!!  Thanks again!

Comment: BTW, the cleanup_file is just a list of extensions.  *.jpg, *.txt, *.nfo, *.svg, *.png, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: @Dan I am going to repeat what I said before. You do not need FORFILES. You are making your script extremely inefficient by doing so.

Comment: @Dan, if all your extensions are on one line separated by commas, a `FOR /F` command will not parse all the extensions.

Comment: Agreed.  However, if the extensions are in list format, 'for /f' does a great job of listing them in the statement, while 'forfiles /s' does a better job of actually finding them in directories with numerous children.  It works, and I am satisfied with the results.  Thanks for the help!